# How to setup digest authentication with HttpClient 4.0.1?

Tags: httpclient, digest

I can't find this information in the tutorial, it seems something is changed since HttpClient 4.0. Can someone show me some code where httpclient is doing requests with a preconfigured digest authentication scheme?

Thanks in advance.